# .NET Filestream.Write() method generates the exception Insufficient system resources exist to complete the requested service. How to solve?

Tags: .net, exception, optimization, resources, filestream

How can I avoid the exception

> Insufficient system resources exist to complete the requested service.

I am using this code to write a pdf document with 190mb, where this.outputPDF is the path of the big PDF, and dataToFile is a array of bites that is already in memory when the exception occurs.

```
        using (FileStream fsFileSigned = new FileStream(this.outputPDF, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            fsFileSigned.Write(dataToFile, 0, dataToFile.Length);
            fsFileSigned.Close();
        }
```

It is a windows service running in a Windows Server 2008 64bits with 2Gb ram.

Comment: It is a low-level Windows errors, typically caused by the kernel memory pool being exhausted.  Handle leaks can be a cause, or the machine just being heavily overloaded.  Running a 64-bit server with only 2 GB of ram most certainly doesn't help.

Answer (score 2):

Your system specification suggests that it may be running low on resources but that's just a vague guess... If you really want to do this stuff within these constraints, you may want to write to the file in manageable chunks.

Just open the output file in append mode and write (lets say) 5 MB of your data at a time and close it. Keep repeating this until all data is appended. This may be dreadfully slow compared to original single-write approach but it may work in low resource situations.